# TYPO3 Repository outside controller

Tags: typo3-extensions

I am using TYPO3 10.4.15 and try to write a TcaProcFunc for my own extension.

```
namespace HGA\Album\UserFunc;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use HGA\Album\Domain\Repository\AlbumRepository;
use HGA\Album\Domain\Model\Album;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\PersistenceManagerInterface;

class TcaProcFunc
{   
    /**
     * @param array $config
     *
     */
    public function getLink(&$config)
    {
        $ret = [];
        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $albumRepository= $objectManager->get(AlbumRepository::class);
        $albums = $albumRepository->findAll();
        foreach ($albums as $album){
            $ret[] = ["Test1","Test1"];
        }
        $i = count($albums);
            error_log("Album: " . $i, 0 );
        $ret[] = ["Test", "Test"];
        $config['items'] = $ret;
//      error_log("UserFunc: " . var_export($config, true), 0);
    }

}
```

The problem is, that `findall()` does not provide any result. `$albums`is empty, but there is one record inside the database.

HGA is my vendor name and Album the extension name. The TcaProcFunc is in generell is working, but I don't have any access to the extension database.

Can anybody tell me, what is wrong with my code or how I what I can do to findthe problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did it with ConnectionPool

```
namespace HGA\Album\UserFunc;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

class TcaProcFunc
{   
    /**
     * @param array $config
     *
     */
    public function getLink(&$config)
    {
        $ret = [];
        $albums = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
           ->getConnectionForTable('tx_album_domain_model_album')
           ->select(
          ['uid', 'album_artist', 'album'],
              'tx_album_domain_model_album',
               []
           )->fetchAll();       
        foreach ($albums as $album){
            $ret[] = [$album['album_artist'] . ": " . $album['album'], $album['uid']];
        }
        $config['items'] = $ret;
    }
}
```